# Viewport width/height (10vw) max/min font size

Tags: html, css

I've just stated using the viewport unit, not sure how to handle this so any feedback is appreciated.

I've created element

```
<h4>text here</h4>
```

added some style

```
h4 {font-size:7vp;}
```

This is excellent on mobiles devices, phone and laptops. But once the screen size exceeds that of a laptop to keep up with the viewport width, the height of the text gets two large for the viewport height.

If you know what I mean.

Im looking for something like

```
max-size:
```

but more like

```
max-font-size:
```

Comment: If my answer solves your problem I'd really appreciate if you marked it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `max-font-size` but you can use `media queries` to detect when the window is now desktop size. For example:

```
media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

This will override your font-size from vh to px when the window size is larger than 768px.

Note: To use media queries make sure you add this tag in your main html file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, you answer is the does answer the question, I was just hoping there was something akin to max-font-size or max-font-height

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't :(